# How to fix the error: "RankException was unhandled"?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I get this error whenever the following code is run.

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim mg As Array = {{2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}}
    Dim pt As Point = New Point(2, 3)

    If mg(1)(0) = pt.X And mg(1)(1) = pt.Y Then 'Checking to see if mg(1) and pt are equal
        Debug.Print("pt and mg are equal")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you even try Googling it first?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.rankexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: It was more a question of how do I fix my code so I don't get that error.

Comment: You should have specified that then.

Comment: Do you know how I could fix it?

Comment: Which line exactly does the error occur on?

Comment: The one with the comment.

Comment: Why don't you put your code in a try-catch block and get more information about the exception.

Comment: "Attempted to operate on an array with the incorrect number of dimensions." How to do you operate on an Array of Arrays? I tried to print mg(1)(0) and mg(1) and got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, for a [2-dimensional array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx#BKMK_DeclaringAnArray):

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim mg(,) As Integer = {{2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}}
    Dim pt As System.Drawing.Point = New System.Drawing.Point(2, 3)

    If mg(1, 0) = pt.X And mg(1, 1) = pt.Y Then 'Checking to see if mg(1) and pt are equal
        Debug.Print("pt and mg are equal")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason why you're not declaring `mg` as a `Point()`? Seems like this would simplify the comparison:

```
Dim mg As Point() = New Point(){New Point(2, 2), New Point(2, 3), New Point(2, 4), New Point(2, 5), New Point(2, 6)}

If mg(1) = pt Then...
```

Otherwise, as others have said, your array declaration is wrong. It looks like you can access the values in your `mg` array with [Array.GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/c2cf72s5%28v=vs.100%29).

```
If mg.GetValue(1, 0) = pt.X AndAlso mg.GetValue(1, 1) = pt.Y Then...
```

Comment: You beat me to the declaring mg as a Point() while I was switching OSes. So a +1.

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing is declaring an array(,) when what your code is expecting is an array()().

To use your code as-is, bar the declaration, declare the array like this:

```
Dim mg = {({2, 2}), ({2, 3}), ({2, 4}), ({2, 5}), ({2, 6})}
```

To modify your code to use the declaration as-is, do it like this:

```
If mg(1, 0) = pt.X AndAlso mg(1, 1) = pt.Y Then
```

(I use [Option Infer On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx).)

Ref: [How to: Initialize an Array Variable in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13tek7e.aspx).